# Haskell functional dependency a b -> c depending on c?

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies, type-families

Consider the following Haskell code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances,
    FunctionalDependencies #-}

class C a b c | a b -> c

instance C (l (i,j)) (r i j)   j
instance C (l i j)   (r (i,j)) j
-- Conflict between the following two lines
instance C (l (i,j)) (r (i,j)) j  
instance C (l i j)   (r i j)   j
```

Here, GHC yields a functional dependencies error between the last two lines. 
If I drop any of the last two instance declarations, the code compiles. I tried an analogue using type families, which also produced a conflict. My first question is: Why do the last two lines conflict, while the other declarations all work fine together?

In addition, if I change the very last line to

```
instance C (l i j)   (r i j)   i
```

GHC accepts the code. 
This seems quite weird, since the only thing that changes is the dependent type variable c. Can somebody explain this behavior?

Comment: Just to make sure. If you remove both of the first two instances there's still an error, right?

Comment: @genisage Yes, it depends only on the last two instances

Comment: I can't reproduce the second part here. `instance C (l i j) (r i j) i` causes a conflict for me. (on ghc 7.8.3)

Comment: @genisage No conflict here, also ghc(i) 7.8.3

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I tried it again and still got a conflict. I'm currently using windows and the Haskell platform.

Comment: @genisage I compiled with ghc 7.6.3 and ghc 6.12.x

Comment: @genisage Me too! Curious...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen On my home computer (Ubuntu, ghc(i) 7.8.4) it still shows a conflict. Both of my installations are from the last week, so maybe it was a bug and they fixed it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last two instances have a conflicting unification.  Let me use completely different variable names:

```
C (a c (d,e)) (b c (d,e)) e
vs.
C (a c (d,e)) (b c (d,e)) (d,e)
```

In particular, your `l` from the third instance can be unified with a type constructor which already has an argument applied.

Changing your `j` to `i` makes the last one instead:

```
C (a c (d,e)) (b c (d,e)) c
```

I still don't understand why that doesn't give a complaint.  Perhaps it's because you *can* assign the types such that `c = e`, but not such that `e = (d,e)` (that would give an infinite type which Haskell doesn't allow), but it still seems like a dubious thing to allow.  Perhaps this is even a GHC bug.

The other instance combinations don't conflict because when you try to unify them, you end up with contradictions similar to the `e = (d,e)` above, but in the non-dependent parts, so they cannot match.

Comment: I'd agree with you. Experimenting, I found that `class C a b ; instance C (l (i,j)) (r (i,j)) ; instance C (l i j) (r i j)` is _accepted_ without mentioning the overlap (!?). Maybe now some overlaps are being detected only later, when a method is called (just guessing here).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the unification process. @chi: Indeed, if I try to write a class method `f :: a -> b -> c` I get a complaint abount incoherency when calling `f`